# java webdriver access to restricted site

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm wondering how I can log in to a site that is restricted, using WebDriver. 
When you get to the site it says: "The server (server name) requires a username and password. the server says: Restricted Files." This message box does not provide the option to inspect element or see any source, so I can't get a frame name or anything. Is there a way to handle this? this is a dev site and is protected. Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only way to do this - send username in the URL. so if the site is for example `http://www.example.com/restricted.html` you have to access it like this

```
driver.get("http://username:password@www.example.com/restricted.html");
```

The above pseudocode applies to Webdriver  in Java, where `driver` is valid instance of WebDriver